# How to replace a tab with a character in a file

Tags: text-processing

the given file looks like

```
CHrIS   john    herzog  10001   Marketing
tim             johnson 10002   IT
ruth    bertha  Hendric 10003   HR
christ  jason   hellan  10004   Marketing
```

my code:

```
readFile=$1

#error checking to see if the file exists and is not a directory
if [ ! -f "$readFile" ]
then
    #echo failed no param passed
    exit 1
else
    #reads in the file and stores the information into the variabel var.
    while read -r var
    do
        #echo $var
        fName=$(echo "$var" | cut -f1 | awk '{print $1}')
        mName=$(echo "$var" | cut -f2 | awk '{print $2}' | tr "\t" "x")

        echo $mName
    done < $readFile
fi
```

How can I get the middle tab in line 2 with `tim   (needs to be an X)     johnson   10002 IT` to change into an X?

Comment: yeah, I can't edit the file. Could you show me the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

lets say the content is stored in a file "file"

```
cat file | sed -E 's/    /        x/'
```

would give

```
CHrIS   john    xherzog  10001   Marketing
tim     x         johnson 10002   IT
ruth    xbertha  Hendric 10003   HR
christ  jason   hellan  10004   Marketing
```

As to why write the `sed` in the aforementioned way, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/sed-not-recognizing-t-instead-it-is-treating-it-as-t-why)

Comment: it added an X in front of Bertha though

Comment: i got it, between bertha and ruth it wasn't tabular, it was spaced.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming those are `{tab}` characters in the spacing...

You'll never see a tab in your `awk` or `tr` because it's already been used as the field separator character by `cut`.

It looks like you're trying to replace an empty field with `x`. If this is the case you can use constructs like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
while IFS= read -r line
do
    first=$(echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $1}')
    middle=$(echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $2}')
    last=$(echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $3}')
    id=$(echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $4}')
    dept=$(echo "$line" | awk -F$'\t' '{print $5}')

    echo "First is ${first:-x}"
    echo "Middle is ${middle:-x}"
    echo "Last is ${last:-x}"
    echo "Id is ${id:-x}"
    echo "Dept is ${dept:-x}"
    echo
done
```

We can't split with `IFS=$'\t' read -r first middle last...` because `read` splits on runs of whitespace (space, tab, newline) rather than single instances. (Actually it's more complicated than that; look up "Word Splitting" in the manual page for the full details.)

I've stayed away from using `echo "$line" | cut -f1`, etc., because if `cut` runs out of fields it reuses the last one it finds.

As an alternative to "${middle:-x}" you can actually assign `x` to the variable if it's unset with the construct `${middle:=x}`. Prefix that with the no-op command `:` if you want the assignment to happen by itself (and not as a side-effect of some other command):

```
: ${middle:=x}
echo "The middle is $middle"    # Will be 'x' if it was unset
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that into my code, could you explain a bit further :)

Comment: would `echo "${$3: -x}"` work?

Comment: @ChrisZog no, because that doesn't follow the pattern of `"$middle"` → `"${middle:-x}"`. You'd use `echo "${3:-x}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file is tab-delimited from the start:

```
$ cat -t file
CHrIS^Ijohn^Iherzog^I10001^IMarketing
tim^I^Ijohnson^I10002^IIT
ruth^Ibertha^IHendric^I10003^IHR
christ^Ijason^Ihellan^I10004^IMarketing
```

And assuming that the task is to insert an `x` in any empty field in column 2.

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 == "" { $2 = "x" } { print }' file
CHrIS   john    herzog  10001   Marketing
tim     x       johnson 10002   IT
ruth    bertha  Hendric 10003   HR
christ  jason   hellan  10004   Marketing
```

The `awk` script will use tabs as input and output separators, and will detect any empty fields in column 2 and change these to an `x`.

Answer (score 0):

## Sed

Assuming that your "sed" understands the "\t" "\n" escape sequences. There are WAs in case it doesn't. But those will detract from the logic of the code.

```
 sed -e '
    s/\t/\n/;      # 1st field sep => \n , a char sure to not be in PS by definition
    s/\n\t/\tx\t/; # incase 2nd field empty then we will see the \n\t else not
    s/\n/\t/;      # just incase 2nd fields was nonempty, preceding would fail so deal here
' yourfile
```

## Perl

```
perl -F"\t" -pale '$F[1] || s/^\S+\t(?=\t)/$&x/' yourfile
```